# Program akes only 1 alphabet input and exits while leaving remaining code unexecuted, why?

Tags: c++, if-statement, dev-c++

when user input a character and press enters to take next input, output window asks to press any key and exit, please help me out to get remaining code working,

Here is the code

```
char r, R;
char c;

int channels;

int resedential()
{
    // float channelscost = costperchannel*channels;
    // float Bill = channelscost+processingfee+basiccost;
    // cout << "Dear Customer Here is Your Bill" <<"  "<<Bill<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << " Enter Customer Type" << " " << endl;
    cin >> c;

    if( c == r || R )
    {
        cout << " Enter Customer Type" << " " << endl;
         cin >> c;
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't put an image of the code. Put the actual code. You have copy and paste buttons.

Comment: The Image doesn't work.

Comment: Image invisible. Paste the code instead.

Comment: Even if the image is visible, don't post images of the code.

Comment: Can you explain what you're code should do? Shoudl it ask for Customer Type until he answered r or R? Or should it only ask one more time?

Comment: `if(c== r||R)` -- This does not do what you think it does.  This should be `if(c== r || c==R)`.

Comment: My mistake guys,

Comment: now the code is visible , its not full code, i actually want to calculate the bill of customers on basis of two inputs , i am having issues on very first input , kindly help me out

Comment: You try to compare the character entered (and stored in the `c` variable) to the `r` variable (declared at the top of the code). What do you think is the value of `r` variable? What do you expect from the comparison?

Comment: "having issues" is not a problem description. What is your question? Is it about the code that is currently commented out? What happens if you uncomment and compile it? Why is that wrong? What do you expect all those zero-initialised variables like `r`, `R`, and `channels` to contain? Should they really be zeroes? Why?

Comment: for now i just need to understand why user cant give the second input, , description is the same

Comment: @underscore_d ''_What do you expect all those unitialised variables like `r`, `R`, and `channels` to contain?_" Since those are global variables - they are guaranteed to be zero-initialized.

Comment: You have already been told that you do the comparison (OR) wrong. Also, you may or may not really want to compare to zeroes in the not-explicitly-initialised global variables, but we can't say because you didn't explain the logic of this program.

Comment: @underscore_d Variables `r`, `R` and `channels` are _not_ uninitialized, but you're correct that it's OP's responsibility to realize that they _are_ initialized, as well as _when_, _why_ and _how_ they are initialized.

Comment: Ok , commented lines are the the step 2 , step 1 is not done yet

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, CiaPan: Edited. I always forget that file-scope variables are zero-initialised, as I don't like to rely on that implicit behaviour in case I move them locally later.

Comment: if user inputs r or R only then 2nd input can be given

Comment: But _what is_ step 1? Is it not clear by now how this `if` is wrong? `if( c == r || R )` is `if( c == 0 || 0 )` is `if( c == false )` (which compares `c` to false/0). To my knowledge you can't enter the null-character `'\0'` on a keyboard, so this will always be false.

Comment: May be it's time lo learn to debug...? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in our [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and the page [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) linked there.

Comment: @underscore_d The "file-scope variables" as you describe it (since, unless you declare variables with internal linkage, aren't only visible in the current file - they are visible globally - in your entire program) aren't limited to this behavior. Any variable with `static`, or `thread_local` storage duration is zero initialized.

Comment: `char r, R;` declares two variables named `r` and `R` of type `char` and zero-initializes them. Did you maybe mean _literally_ `'r'` and `'R'`? -> `if(c == 'r' || c == 'R')`??

Comment: I suppose you don't really know how your program works, in other words: what you actually wrote. If that's correct, you'll probably will not know why the proposed solution would work, either, even if you get a complete solution here. Please learn the basics of the language you use, so that you understand what you _need_ to achieve. Mixing arbitrary symbols randomly in a hope they'll magically do themselves what you need won't work. The program will not guess what you want, it's you who must know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I recognise, is that your if statement doesn't do what you think it does. Right now you aren't checking if c is equal to R.

**Fixed Code:**

```
if(c == r || c == R)
{
    cout << "Enter Customer Type " << endl;
    cin >> c;
}
```

Also check that there are actual values in r and R. So it doesn't compare to a constant `(char(0))` – ASCII code NUL, resulting from default initialization of file-scoped variables to zero.

**Example:**

```
char r = 'A';
char R = 'B';
```

Comment: Variables `c` and `r` do **not** contain null, they contain ASCII **NUL**, that is `(char)0`, if not explicitly initialised otherwise. BTW, there is no `null` in C++, but there exists a C-compliant macro symbol `NULL` and a C++ native constant `nullptr`.

Comment: @MathewHD I tried to fix an expression, which might cause confusion of variable and constant. Please review (and feel free to revert if the new contents doesn't reflect what you meant).